# AVAudioPlayer Plays Sound Depending Where I Create the AVAudioPlayer Instance

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a class with an `AVAudioPlayer` property. I set the URL for the sound file in one method (say Func A) and create the `AVAudioPlayer` instance and play the sound in another method (say Func B). The sound plays fine.

However, if I create the `AVAudioPlayer` in Func A where I set the URL for the sound file and simply play the sound in Func B, the sound plays intermittently.

The sound is a sound effect which plays whenever a button is pressed. The button can be pressed repeatedly and the sound effect should play repeatedly.

I have tried customising (and activating) the audio session for the app, in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in my `AppDelegate` class, though this did not seem to help.

I don't understand why the two approaches have different results. I wanted to use the latter approach to avoid instantiating an `AVAudioPlayer` every time the sound is played (remembering it can be played repeatedly).

Also, for sounds effects which are played repeatedly, is there any benefit in calling `prepareToPlay` each time I wish to play the sound?

Approach A (sound plays intermittently):

```
import AVFoundation
...
class myClass: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate
{
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sound: URL?
    let soundFile: String
    ...
    func LoadSound() {
        sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFile, withExtension: "mp3")

        if let _sound = sound {
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: _sound)
            catch {
                ...
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    } // end of func LoadSound
    ...
    func playSoundFX() {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    ...
}
```

Approach B (sound plays fine):

```
import AVFoundation
...
class myClass: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate
{
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sound: URL?
    let soundFile: String
    ...
    func LoadSound() {
        sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFile, withExtension: "mp3")
    }
    ...
    func playSoundFX() {
        if let _sound = sound {
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: _sound)
                audioPlayer.play()
            catch {
                ...
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: take a Weak reference of AVAudioPlayer and nil it everytime when its function is done

Comment: make use of Optional Instead of reinitialise Same variable again and again make it nil before second initialisation takes place

Comment: Using this way you will be able to play sound as many time you want, Initialise session at once in app then just Payer initialisation need to be done, shall I share Demo code ?

Comment: Are class properties created as weak references by default? class bound properties such as outlets "Yes", Variable we create like var let are not weak we need to make them weak by using optionals or lazy war reference

Comment: I Suggested to make use a weak reference for Audio Player as **var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?** instead of **var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()**

Comment: I need to ponder your comments. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, my suggestion was to just make use of optional so in case you need to Reinitialise Player , you can set Earlier allocated Player as Nil